# how to get app listed in movies section on facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am working on a movie detail sharing application integrated with Facebook.

I am posting the post with default video object properties but still the app does not show in the Films section.

When I click edit it shows Goodreads and Pinterest (and other apps) listed but not mine.

[image]

**I want to get my app listed in this section.**

Comment: Do you have implemented an Open Graph collection in your app yet?

Comment: yeah but for following facebook not allowing for videos

Comment: is your app listed via developers.facebook.com/apps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ,for the Moment, Assign the Movies & TV Category to an App. That fell under the `Entertainment` Category.

Read also -> [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/03/08/improving-facebook-for-books--movies--tv-and-fitness/)

Apps like Netflix, Rotten Tomatoes, Goodreads have integrated with sections to let people add their favorite media content to timeline. To encourage people to share with friends they rolled out the ability to rate content directly on timeline and add ratings from apps.

[image]